# wallet that does not abstract change addresses?

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets, change, deterministic-wallets

I wanted a hands on approach to see change adresses myself instead of hiding away all the details.

I also want to see non-deterministic wallets just for education so that I can understand. When we need to make regular backups in non-deterministics wallets might apply actually making a back up of change adresses?

This type of question has not been asked before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are indeed wallets that allow a more manual and granular control of UTXOs, in my experience desktop wallets such as Electrum are more likely to have this feature. Mobile wallets are often more tuned for ease-of-use.

The best way to find something you like is to simply try a few and see what works best for you. Check out the Bitcoin.org wallet page, and always ensure you download wallet software from a trusted source, verify developer signatures, etc.

> I also want to see non-deterministic wallets just for education so that I can understand. When we need to make regular backups in non-deterministics wallets might apply actually making a back up of change adresses?

The backup of a non-deterministic wallet will include **every** address the wallet has used, including change addresses. This will be true whether or not the wallet shows the user the change addresses.